# How to use Pdfsharp to read form fields of pdf file in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, pdfsharp

I want to use Pdfsharp to perform some operation's on pdf file as it is free.    But I don't know how to use it.
I just try something like this,

```
     string pdfTemplate = @"C:\Users\Tudip\Downloads\State Tax Forms\State Tax Forms\Louisiana L-4 (1).pdf";
    var doc = PdfReader.Open(pdfTemplate);
// Code for Read pdf fields 
// Code for insert data in pdf fields
```

Comment: If you research a bit you'd find at least this hello [world sample](http://www.pdfsharp.com/PDFsharp/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=15&Itemid=35)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I display a PDF using PdfSharp in ASP.Net MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15121876/how-do-i-display-a-pdf-using-pdfsharp-in-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: I want to read pdf form fields and insert data in that fields. But on its official website it display below line.

Read content of interactive form fields (AcroForms) (still under construction) http://www.pdfsharp.net/(X(1)S(sr5d2setqqk0sijkzv3cb4ze))/PDFsharpFeatures.ashx

Answer (score 1):

Download the source code for version 1.32 and check out the sample in the ReadFormFields folder.
https://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfsharp/files/pdfsharp/PDFsharp%201.32/

Form fields should also work with version 1.50 of PDFsharp.

Comment: Here's the link to the same example on GitHub.
https://github.com/DavidS/MigraDoc/blob/master/PDFsharp/samples/Samples%20C%23/Based%20on%20GDI%2B/FillFormFields/Program.cs

I'm not sure which is the official source.

Comment: SourceForge is the official source, DavidS is not official. The current official version on GitHub does not include the ReadFormFields sample. It's address: https://github.com/empira/PDFsharp-samples