# PDFsharp not giving pdf file in response

Tags: c#, .net, pdfsharp

I am working on export functionality using PDFsharp in .Net MVC I am not getting any error in my code but not getting PDF file in response.

I have tried doing it manually writing it to specific path with the help of : `System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(path1, bytes);` and it's working perfectly, but I am not getting PDF in Response with the help of

```
Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
Response.OutputStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
```

Anyone have faced this type of issue or someone from community please help
Here is my code :

```
public bool ExportPdf(string htmlcontenttbl)
    {
        Response.ClearContent();
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", 
"attachment;filename=Myfile.pdf");
        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";

        Response.Charset = "";
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);

        PdfDocument document = 
PdfGenerator.GeneratePdf(htmlcontenttbl.ToString(), PdfSharp.PageSize.A4, 
30);

        var config = new PdfGenerateConfig();
        config.PageOrientation = PageOrientation.Landscape;
        config.PageSize = PageSize.A4;
        config.MarginBottom = 30;
        config.MarginTop = 30;

        byte[] bytes = null;
        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            document.Save(stream, true);
            bytes = stream.ToArray();
        }

        var path1 = Server.MapPath("~/Images/" + 
                    DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.Ticks + "result.pdf");
        //System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(path1, bytes);

        //Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
        //Response.OutputStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

        Response.Flush();
        Response.End();

        return true;

    }
```

thank you,

Comment: You don't need a file. Maybe the problem is with the code you are not showing. Maybe this post can help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15123343/162529